# How to concatenate a number of rows based on a condition

Tags: excel

I am trying to concatenate a number of rows into a single cell based on a condition.

```
A  B    C     D
1  bb1  cc1   bb1 cc1 cc2 cc3 
0       cc2
0       cc3 
1  bb2  cc4   bb2 cc4 cc5 cc6 
0       cc5
0       cc6
```

I am trying to get " bb1 cc1 cc2 cc3 " as result in the D column.
Any pointers/help would be great.

Comment: Please clearify your question and what you acutally want to do. Please add some Information e.g. a screenshot

Comment: Are the number of blank cells in column B or zeroes in column A consistent?

Answer (score 0):

You might try in D2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",B2&" "&C2&" "&C3&" "&C4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but it looks like you want column D to keep concatenating until you hit another 1 in column A. Without VBA, you can't set an "until" kind of condition, so you have to just guess at the maximum number of times you'll have to iterate is and put that in the formula.

```
A   B   C   Result
1   bb1 cc1 bb1 cc1 cc2 cc3
0       cc2 
0       cc3 
1   bb2 cc4 bb2 cc4 cc5 cc6
0       cc5 
0       cc6
```

I got this using this:

```
 =IF(A2,B2&" "&C2&IF(A3,"",B3&" "&C3)&IF(A4,"",B4&" "&C4),"")
```

Let us know if that's not what you needed.